# Show responsive menu with one click instead of two

Tags: jquery

I have come up with the following to show (scrollDown) a menu when a `.menubutton` is clicked and to hide (scrollUp) the menu again when a link is clicked within the menu:

```
var navi = $('#navigation').hide();

$('.menubutton').toggle(function() {
    navi.slideDown();
}, function() {
    navi.slideUp();
});

$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    navi.slideUp();
});
```

The problem is, if a menu link has been clicked, the `.menubutton` has to be clicked TWICE to display (scrollDown) the menu again.

Any idea why this is? I want `.menubutton` to respond with 1 click each time.

Comment: Without the HTML it's hard to do anything but guess. A jsFiddle would be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.menubutton` is on a toggle.  So it calls one function, then the other, and so on.  Instead of using `.toggle`, try using `.slideToggle`.

```
$('.menubutton').click(function() {
    navi.slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `slideUp` directly when clicking a navigation element, so the `.menubutton` toggle is still in a state where it will also call `slideUp` on its next click. Try invoking the `.menubutton`'s `click` instead:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('.menubutton').click();
});
```